# Take object as argument and NOT as instance/reference

Tags: python, pygame

I am currently coding a game with pygame and I have ran into a problem with objects as arguments. So, 1) I have an object class, and 2) A function that takes in a object and an integer and appends the object into an array X times, where X equals integer, then the function returns the array, and 3) A run function that initializes the objects.

Each of these parts are in different files. They each import pygame and 3) imports 1) and 2)

1) File: Objects

```
import pygame

class Obstacle(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
def __init__(self, screen, settings):
    # Initialize the lander
    #make the lander a sprite
    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
    #Keep local copy of screen
    self.screen = screen
    self.image = pygame.image.load('lander.png')
    self.imageCopy = self.image.copy()
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    #Start with each new lander at the top of the screen
    self.rect.centerx = random.randint(50, settings.screen_width - 50)
    self.rect.centery = 0
```

2) File: GameMethods

```
import pygame

def random_array(number_needed, object):
#Takes in the number of objects to be created in an array
#and returns that new array
#Use: to make an array that holds randomly located objects
number_assigned = 0
array = []
while number_assigned < number_needed:
    array.append(object)
    number_assigned += 1
return array
```

3) File: Main

```
from Objects import Obstacles
import GameMethods as gm

def run_game():
"""Main function to start game and run top-level loop"""
# Initialize pygame, settings and screen object.
pygame.init()
  ....
  some unrelated code
  ....
 number_of_fixed_Obstacles_needed = 5
fixed_Obstacles_array = gm.random_array(number_of_fixed_Obstacles_needed, fixedObstacle(screen, settings)
```

The Problem arises in 3) when I call gm.random_array. I am not 100% sure but when I call fixedObstacle as an argument, it is taking the instance or the memory reference of the object and appending the SAME Obstacle 5 times. I am trying to make it append 5 DIFFERENT Obstacle to the array.

If I put this inside the run function instead, it works

```
 number_of_Obstacles_assigned = 0
 Obstacles_array = []
 while number_of_Obstacles_assigned < number_of_Obstacles_needed:
        Obstacles_array.append(fixedObstacle(screen, settings)
        number_of_Obstacles_assigned += 1
```

PS. I am trying to make a function do it because have many Object classes that I would like to append to different arrays so calling gm.random_array(number, object) is a lot quicker than calling the while-loop and it also make the code more object-oriented.

Comment: When you assign objects, it doesn't make a copy of it, it just assigns a reference to the same object. If you want copies you need to do that explicitly.

Comment: `array.append(object)` appends a reference to the object the name `object` refers to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[REWRITED] Finally understand your problem. You need creation of different objects using different classnames. So pass the creator as one of the function parameters:

```
import pygame

def random_array(number_needed, Creator, screen, settings):
    #Takes in the number of objects to be created in an array
    #and returns that new array
    #Use: to make an array that holds randomly located objects
    number_assigned = 0
    array = []
    while number_assigned < number_needed:
        array.append(Creator(screen, settings))
        number_assigned += 1
    return array
```

And then in `Main`:

```
fixed_obstacles1_array = gm.random_array(number_obstacles1, Obstacle1, screen, settings)
fixed_obstacles2_array = gm.random_array(number_obstacles2, Obstacle2, screen, settings)
...
```

And finally you can concatenate those arrays if you want to

```
all_obstacles = fixed_obstacles1_array + fixed_obstacles2_array
```

Or even more object-oriented way:

```
all_obstacles = []
disered_obstacles = [Obstacle1, Obstacle2, ObstacleN]
numbers_needed = [42, 3, 17]

for obstacle, number in zip(disered_obstacles, numbers_needed):
    all_obstacles += gm.random_array(number, obstacle, screen, settings)
```

And now you have a nice array with all obstacles.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. FixedObstacles is Obstacles. I forgot to change the name when I typed the code.      So essential what I am trying to do is to create a function that will be applicable to any object. This is because I have many classes such as meteors, landingpads, obstacles, lasers, and more that I will take in, and I will have multiple instances of these classes that I have to update and draw. Putting these obstacles into an array will make the updating much easier for me to do. The problem is that when I create the object in the argument, it appends the same object multiple times.

Comment: @JohnnyCortez so my suggestion is to move object creation into that random function. And then use as `fixed_Obstacles_array = gm.random_array(number_of_fixed_Obstacles_needed, screen, settings)` in `Main`.

Comment: @JohnnyCortez check my edit, rewrited it as I think I understand your problem now.

Comment: Thank you very much! That makes sense. So you can pass a class as an argument without having to put in the arguments inside the class?

Comment: For sure! In Python pretty much everything is an object. Even classes and functions are objects of some special classes. Long story short, that means you can add them into arrays or dictionaries and pass them as arguments to other functions and classes.